# pgrep {process_name} | wc -l returning wrong results

Tags: linux, shell, wc

I have this script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "pgreg --- start"
pgrep 'test.sh'
echo "pgrep --- end"

process_count=`pgrep 'test.sh' | wc -l`
echo "process_count = $process_count"

pids=`pgrep 'test.sh'`;
fixed_count_process=`echo $pids | wc -w`
echo "pids = $pids";
echo "fixed_count_process = $fixed_count_process"
```

The output of this script is always:

```
pgreg --- start
56516
pgrep --- end
process_count = 2
pids = 56516
fixed_count_process = 1
```

I can't find any logical explanation why storing the output of `pgrep` in a variable before passing it to `wc` gives the right results. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So at first we do `./test.sh` from the terminal. So we have a single process with process name `test.sh`.

> ```
> process_count=`pgrep 'test.sh' | wc -l`
> ```

The command substitution invoked by backticks runs a subshell. The subshell is a separate process and has the same process name `test.sh`. So there are now two processes with different pids that are having the process name `test.sh`. Thus `pgrep` returns two lines.

This could be for example inspected with:

```
process_count=$(
        ps -e -o pid,comm | grep 'test.sh' >&2
        echo BASHPID=$BASHPID \$=$$ >&2
        pgrep 'test.sh' | wc -l
)
```

with outputs on stderr:

```
 495463 test.sh
 495466 test.sh
BASHPID=495466 $=495463
```

The `495466` is the pid of the subshell and `495463` is the pid of the parent shell process.

When you do:

> ```
> pids=`pgrep 'test.sh'`;
> ```

this outputs a single pid. This is because bash has an optimization, that on specific circumstances (ex. no `trap`s) when only one process is left to execute in a shell, it optimizes and doesn't call `fork()+exec()` instead it calls just `exec`, because there will be no next process to run, so it can just exit. The inner subshell with the process name `test.sh` exists only for a short moment, the subshell detects that there is only a single command to run, so it skips `fork()`, just executes `exec("pgrep")` and becomes a process with process name `pgrep`. That is why you do not see another pid in this case.

Notes: Please do not use backticks `. Use `$(...)` instead.

Extra: More subshells! The following

```
echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(pgrep 'test.sh' | wc -l)")")"
# would output 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In that case, why does ```pids=`pgrep 'test.sh'`;``` returns a single pid if the backticks run a new subshell?